# AngularJS - Configure multiple base tags

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, base-tag

When using angularjs, there is the `#` that needs to be removed. To accomplish that you need to set the following:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

and also add the base tag so when the page refreshes it works normally. The point is if it's defined as `<base href="http://example.com/">` then it only works from this url. i.e I can not access the website from `www.example.com`.

So is there a way to configure some sort of multiple base so that when one fails, it gets replaced with the other?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<base href="/"></base>` - for `ROOT` webapps.

`<base href="/webappName/"></base>` - for non `ROOT` webapps.

Also, you only need to use the the `<base>` tag if you have relative `<a>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

`<base href="/">`

Or if you don't want to use base:

`$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false
});`